# How to enter data to MySQL by using foreign key value?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables:

- Table 1 - PRODUCT (product_id, product_name, price)
- Table 2 - ORDERS (order_id, product_id, quantity), where product_id is a FOREIGN KEY from Table 1

I have a product with:

```
product_id=1
product_name='Computer'
price=2500
```

How can I enter new data to table ORDERS (i.e. add a new order) by using product_name from table PRODUCT instead of entering product_id. I want to enter (for example in Stored procedures) product_name (f.e. 'Computer') and as output it ads a new row to table ORDERS with relevant product_id (i.e. 1)

If I use INSERT command to enter data into table ORDERS I need to write values as:
(1,1,2)- order_id, product_id, quantity.
However I want to write as: (1, 'Computer', 2), so that it automatically adds 1 instead of 'Computer' to table ORDERS.

Comment: Are your product names unique?  If so, you could write a stored procedure that looks up the relevent id from a product name, then runs the INSERT statement

Comment: It does not really make sense to me, it's an id, you have to provide an id

Comment: @Mickmackusa I'll bet there's a good dupe for this, but I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created it as product_id then the expectation is to supply the id itself at the time of insert, not value of that Id. One thing can be done here is to have a sub-query in your insert statement:

```
insert into ORDERS (order_id, product_id, quantity)
values (1, (select max(product_id) from PRODUCT where product_name='Computer'), 2);
```

The sub-query will fetch the product_id for your string passed. I have used max(product_id) just in case you have duplicates in the PRODUCT Table.

Note, if you are using a stored procedure then this can be done using a declared variable as two steps as well.

Comment: That works! Thank you man